# Python - Questions for the different use of comma

Tags: python

Recently, I am solving problems [No. 113 Path Sum II](https://leetcode.com/problems/path-sum-ii/) on LeetCode and I find a [solution](https://leetcode.com/problems/path-sum-ii/discuss/484120/Python-3-(beats-~100)-(nine-lines)-(DFS)) online.

> Given a binary tree and a sum, find all root-to-leaf paths where each path's sum equals the given sum.
>   Code as below:

```
class Solution:
    def pathSum(self, R: TreeNode, S: int) -> List[List[int]]:
        A, P = [], []
        def dfs(N):
            if N == None: return
            P.append(N.val)
            if (N.left,N.right) == (None,None) and sum(P) == S: A.append(list(P))
            else: dfs(N.left), dfs(N.right)
            P.pop()
        dfs(R)
        return A


- Junaid Mansuri
- Chicago, IL
```

I would like to ask some questions based on the above code to help me understand how Python works more.

1. Why do we need to use list(), **A.append(list(P))**, to successfully append the list into A if P itself is already a list?
2. What happens when the interpreter runs **dfs(N.left), dfs(N.right)**. Both of the function will append a value into P, but they seem don't affect the other functions(like they are running at the exact same time with the exact same P), is it something like multithreading?
3. A related question of the above, is **A, P = [ ], [ ]** works with same concept as **dfs(N.left), dfs(N.right)**? If not, what is the difference?
4. what does **P.pop()** pop indeed, I mean which value will be poped out if both **dfs(N.left)** and **dfs(N.right)** runs? I mean, will there be two P after the two functions run?

**Updates (more question)**

```py
10    while head != None:
11        if id(head.next) in hashMap:    return True
12        head = head.next
13        hashMap.add(id(head.next))
```

> Line 13: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'next'

The above is part of the code. It just simply look into a linked list. It will show an error as above which I think is normal when it reaches the end of the linked list.

What I want to understand is that if the code changed as below, there will be no error and the code run successfully. Is that related to the comma or there is another reason that makes it runs?

```py
10    while head != None:
11        if id(head.next) in hashMap:    return True
12        head, _ = head.next, hashMap.add(id(head.next))
```

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a substitute for guides, tutorials, or documentation. See: [ask], [tour], [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An internet search will point you to lots of articles on depth-first search.

To answer your immediate questions.

> 1. Why do we need to use list(), A.append(list(P)), to successfully
>      append the list into A if P itself is already a list?

A.append(list(P))

Uses the list constructor to make a shallow copy of P to add to A.

Otherwise, if you just used:

```
A.append(P)
```

then the list in A will change every time P changes

> 2. What happens when the interpreter runs dfs(N.left), dfs(N.right). Both
>      of the function will append a value into P, but they seem don't affect
>      the other functions(like they are running at the exact same time with
>      the exact same P), is it something like multithreading?

These functions are run sequentially.  First dfs(N.left) followed by dfs(N.right).

This performs a depth-first search (DFS) on the left subtree, followed by a DFS on right subtree.

Each function is run for its side-effect of updating A and P.

> 3. A related question of the above, is A, P = [ ], [ ] works with same
>      concept as dfs(N.left), dfs(N.right)? If not, what is the difference?
>      what does P.pop() pop indeed, I mean which value will be poped out if
>      both dfs(N.left) and dfs(N.right) runs? I mean, will there be two P
>      after the two functions run?

Variable A and P are local variables of pathSum.  dfs being a nested function within pathSum has access to these local variables.  Thus there is only one A and one P which dfs updates as it is called recursively.

```
A, P = [], []
```

Is initializing A, P (done once within pathSum).

```
dfs(N.left), dfs(N.right)
```

Is calling the dfs methods on the left and right subnodes, which performs updates on A and P as the recursive calls run.

> 4. what does P.pop() pop indeed, I mean which value will be poped out if
>      both dfs(N.left) and dfs(N.right) runs? I mean, will there be two P
>      after the two functions run?

```
P.pop()
```

Removes the last value appended to list P.

dfs(N.left) and dfs(N.right) are run one after the other.  For example with N correspoding the value = 1:

[image: Tree]

```
dfs(N.left), dfs(N.right)
```

First dfs(N.left) will recursively traverse nodes with values of:
   2, 4, 5

Then, dfs(N.right) will traverse the node with value 3.

The values of A, P will be updated during the traversal.  P  contains the path to the current node.  When we branch left (i.e. DFS(N.left) the left path is added to P.  When we return we need to remove this (thus P.pop()).  Similarly, N.right() is run.

When we have traversed both the left and right children, we remove the current node with P.pop() and control flow returns to the parent.

**Tuple Abbreviation**

```
a, b is an abbreviation for tuple (a, b)
```

Thus:

```
[], [] computes tuple ([], [])
b, a computes tuple (b, a)
dfs(N.left), dbs(N.right) computes tuple (dfs(N.left), dfs(N.right))
```

Tuples can be [unpacked](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/unpacking-a-tuple-in-python/)

Example:

```
t = (2, 4, 6, 8)
x, y, z, w = t
```

Will have x = 2, y = 4, z = 6, w = 8

With:

```
A, P = [], [] equivalent to A, P = ([], [])
```

Unpacking then has:
    A = [], P = []

With:
    a, b = b, a is equivalent to a, b = (b, a)

Unpacking then has:
    a = b and b == a

In terms of result think of these assignments as occuring in parallel.

So with:

```
(a, b) = (5, 3)

a, b = (b, a) will have a = 3, b = 5 (thus swapping a & b)

DFS(N.left), DFS(N.right) is computing the tuple(DFS(N.left, DFS(N.right)).
```

This necessitates running DFS on N.left and N.right.

The resulting tuple is discarded, but this has the desired effect of updating A & P as DFS is run recursively.

Comment: Your answers are very useful.
I would like to ask one more additional question about the use of the comma.
Does comma in {**A, P = [], []**} , {**a, b = b, a**}, and {**dfs(N.left), dfs(N.right)**} means three different things?

Comment: @M0UZ337--I added a subsection on tuple expansion which should shed some light on your question.  The short answer they all make use of two features: 1) tuple creation and 2) unpacking.  Actually the last (i.e. `DFS(N.left), DFS(N.right)` only makes use of tuple creation.  Since there is no assignment it doesn't make use of unpacking.

Comment: Sorry but I am having another further question that I don't know is that related to the use of a comma or not. I have edited and added it to my question. Do you know what is the reason behind that?

Comment: @M0UZ337--related code (i.e. Tree vs. now linked list)?  The reason the old code doesn't work is on line 12, you have `head = head.next`. Followed by `hashMap.add(id(head.next))`.  This is like saying `hashmap.add(id(head.next.next))`. In the new code: `head, _ = head.next, hashMap.add(id(head.next))` the right side is evaluated first.  Thus it computes the tuple (head.next, hashMap.add(id(head.next))` first.  Then by unpacking it assigns head to head.next, and _ to hashMap.add(id(head.next)) (use of _ stores last evaluation but normally indicate we don't care about the value).